# simulate viewdDidLoad?

Tags: swift, macos

I have an user agent app that runs on the tray and a view controller.

I need to set up user defaults for a MASShortcut I have:

```
self.ShortcutView.associatedUserDefaultsKey = "Shortcut"
```

I can do this on the **viewDidLoad** problem is, since it starts minimized it only works after I first click on the tray icon. If I call it from init, the ShortcutView is nil so.

Can I simulate a view load? What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

This question raised my eyebrows beyond their limit and now they are broken, thank you.

Your option is **only one**: revisit your design because "simulating a viewDidLoad" when, in fact, the view didn't load, goes against a lot of principles in software development and in this particular case, against the Cocoa Frameworks as a whole; and the first thing you learn when you start Cocoa development (be it OS X or iOS) is: "*Don't fight the frameworks!*". You are fighting the framework. Go back to the beginning and don't collect your payment.

In all seriousness, don't do that.

If you need *to set up defaults for XXX* set the defaults elsewhere (init?, injection?, etc.) and let the view (which should not have anything to do with the *defaults* find its values when it is, in fact, created in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Got it working by changing my shortcut monitors around.
When I said "simulate a viewload" as was talking about loading it invisible to the user once at startup. Yeah it's a cheap trick, but I never used swift, so I'm just hackin&slashin through it.